# Import almost-JSON data as dataframe in R via API

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to import data in R using api link. Maybe JSON format is not valid.

Here is my API link: [Link](https://malariaapitracker.com/web/api/http/http.php?id=28)

Here is glimpse of data

```
{
    "Date": "2022-01-20, 6:28 pm",
    "Village Code": "324",
    "Age of Patient": "34",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Mode of Diagnosis": "Microscopy",
    "Test Result": "Negative",
    "Type of Malaria": "Mixed (Pv+Pf)",
    "Disease Severity": "SM",
    "Treatment": "ACT + Primaquine",
    "Detection Type": "ACD"
}{
    "Date": "2022-01-26, 2:21 pm",
    "Village Code": "34",
    "Age of Patient": "22",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Mode of Diagnosis": "RDT",
    "Test Result": "Positive",
    "Type of Malaria": "P. falciparum (Pf)",
    "Disease Severity": "SM",
    "Treatment": "Primaquine + Chloroquine",
    "Detection Type": "PCD"
}
```

My desired output is like that:

[image]

How can I import this data even if it's not valid JSON?

Comment: Actually what you've shown is not a valid JSON format. There should be a root element and commas between objects. Did you create the API end point?

Comment: I did not create the API link.  I had to use the link. Is there any way I can use this API link to create a data table like above  screenshot?

Comment: You could try adding `[` at the beginning of the file and `]` at the end and replacing every line consisting of `}{` by `},{`.